PHP: Submit web form, redirect to same page, display alert
Let me preface that it has been 20 years or so since I've worked in PHP, just to set expectations on the code.
I have a web page with a form on it. I want, on submit, to validate the form contents in my PHP script; if valid, do something with it, then redirect the user to the same page and pop up an alert that says either "Thanks, we got your message", or "There was an error".
My code so far is this:
<?php 

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
  
  //validate form
  $isValid = FALSE;
  
  //redirect
  $referer = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
  header("Location: $referer");
  
  //display message
  echo "<script type='text/javascript'> window.onload=showAlert('test message'); </script>";
  
}

?>

The form validation I can handle, the page redirect is working, the alert is not. I tried to echo a script with just the alert(message) in it but that did not work. I poked around on SO and found a suggestion to call a JavaScript function onload but that did not work either.

Do you use a SESSION in your code? That can fix the issue.

You can either redirect to another page/script, or you can output something from the script you've shown us. What you're doing now is issuing a redirect header, but also outputting something. But the redirect header tells the browser to ignore whatever this script outputs, and go somewhere else instead, thus the user will never see what you echo here. (even if you actually redirect back to the same URL, that will mean a fresh GET request, so this code here which only runs when it's a POST won't be executed during the redirected request)

So what you really need to do is put something in the redirect URL which indicates to the receiving script that it should dislpay a message when it loads. And you can either put the content of the message in the URL as a parameter too, or a code which tells it which message to display. Or you could put the message in the PHP Session maybe. Lots of options, and I'm pretty sure this common scenario is covered in lots of places online already.

Thanks, that all makes sense. I figured the alert code was getting washed away because of the redirect. Like I said, its been a while since I worked in PHP but yeah, Sessions seems to make sense. I'll dig around and find some example stuff to work from.

I usually use the current URL ($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']) as the <form>'s action attribute so the form submits to the current page.
When the page reloads, you will then be able to access the input values off of the $_POST variable and render your page's markup based off of the submission data.
Note: Always make sure to use functions like htmlspecialchars to sanitize the data before rendering it into the page, otherwise you'll be vulnerable to hacks such as Cross-site scripting (XSS) attacks.
<?php
  $current_url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

  $first_name = !empty( $_POST['firstName'] ) 
    ? htmlspecialchars( $_POST['firstName'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8' ) 
    : false;
  
  $last_name = !empty( $_POST['lastName'] ) 
    ? htmlspecialchars( $_POST['lastName'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8' ) 
    : false;
  
  $is_valid = $first_name && $last_name;
?>

<?php if ( $is_valid ) { ?>
  <h1><?php echo "$first_name $last_name"; ?></h1>
<?php } ?>

<form action='<?php echo $current_url; ?>' method='POST'>
  <input 
    name="firstName"
    placeholder="First name"
    type="text"
  />  

  <input 
    name="lastName"
    placeholder="Last name"
    type="text"
  />

  <button type="submit">
    Submit
  </button>
</form>

